# Carnage Amongst The Tribes/Amongst the Stars Tagging?

Tags: discussion, tags

This is sort of an anal question, but is there a better tag for Carnage Amongst the Tribes/Stars than [catt]? [carnage-amongst-the-tribes] is too long. I updated my answer to the [release date question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/702/anyone-know-when-carnage-amongst-the-tribes-will-be-released) and got all fussy; feel free to claim I'm being too nitpicky here. :)

Answer (score 2):

You're being too nitpicky.  I don't think we can/should police tags for all 2000+ RPGs in existence.  I assume if someone is posting for some fringe game, they're more in trouch with how its adherents abbreviate/refer to it than we are.  At most we just need to merge dupes.

Answer (score 1):

What about "threesixteen"?  Isn't that better, since they're the same game?